# drawImage() breaks on resized Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm at my wits end on this one.  Trying the very simple base case of drawing an image into an HTML5 Canvas.  The Canvas is much larger than the image and dynamically sized.  I was going to tile several different images, but even with simple drawImage() calls, I can't get the image to properly appear in the canvas.  I simplified the code to what you see below, and still, my image displays a lot larger than it should.  Below, I only try on drawImage at a time, but none work.

```
image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
   canvas = document.getElementById("bigDynamicCanvas");
   context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);  //Nope
   context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height); //Nope
   context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);//Nope
};

image.src = "some.png";
```

This is in Firefox 24.6.0 on CentOS

**EDIT:** I can get images to draw the correct size if the canvas is the same size as the image and I do NOT resize it.  Oddly, the canvas is resized long before any of the above is called.  Then, drawing to the canvas seems to have the effect as if I'm drawing on it's original size and resizing it AFTER, which isn't the order in the program, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was attempting to tile scaled images onto a resized canvas.  The issue is that ALL the `drawImage()` calls were using coordinates related to a scaled canvas size.

So with:

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

And let's say I would resize the canvas

```
$("#mycanvas").width(200).height(200);
```

And then I have tiles that are **10px x 10px**.  I was resizing these images along with the resized canvas.  Considering the above, `scale = 2.0`.

```
// Does NOT work, only 5x5 tiling appears
context.drawImage(image, x*image.width*scale, x*image.height*scale, image.width * scale, image.height * scale);
```

The reason why is that my "resizing" of the canvas was actually just a **style**!

```
<canvas id="fractalCanvas" height="100" width="100" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></canvas>
```

The canvas uses the same coordinates as the originally specified size. So after resizing the canvas:

```
// WORKS, 10x10 tiling @ 200px x 200px, tiles appear as 20x20
context.drawImage(image, x*image.width, x*image.height, image.width, image.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to put `var` before your variables, therefor the references to `image` for instance don't work

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eBjL2/4/**

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="bigDynamicCanvas" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById("bigDynamicCanvas");
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);  //Nope
   context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height); //Nope
   context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);//Nope
};

image.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg";
```

Comment: var is only used to keep the variable scope local. Although I did follow your advice and added var, and kept unique variables throughout the global namespace, but that wasn't the issue.  I've figured it out, but don't really understand it at the moment.